# AVAudioSession switching speaker from receiver speaker to iPhone speaker

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I am using `AVAudioSession` for VOIP and sometimes when the app goes to the background or the volume gets adjusted the speaker switches from the earpiece speaker to the main iPhone speakers. It is almost randomly doing this. Trying to figure out what is causing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you get some answers on your question? I'm also facing same problem as yours.

Comment: Me too.  Anyone have a solution? @JosipB.